# Android Studio: AutocompleteFilter.create cannot resolve symbol after SDK update

Tags: android

After updating to Google Play services 9.4.0 I lost/broke the AutocompleteFilter.

```
List<Integer> acpFilterTypes = new ArrayList<>();
acpFilterTypes.add(Place.TYPE_GEOCODE);

AutocompleteFilter mAutoCompleteFilter = AutocompleteFilter.create(acpFilterTypes); //<-- .create is not recognized as a symbol.
```

What is happening here and why am I not allowed to create a new AutocompleteFilter after SDK updates?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like places were moved to the separate library.

Just add to build.gradle:

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked and this works for me.
Besides adding `play-services-location` library you need also need to add `play-services-places` library.